# ¿Como puedo hacer que mi base de datos con id autoincremental vuelva a poner los id en orden?

Tags: sql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

Tengo una base de datos con id autoincremental, he ido metiendo datos y borrado haciendo pruebas y ahora el id va por 49, lo que quiero es que al añadir registros vuelva a ponerse en orden es decir que si alguien se registra alguien ahora mismo tenga id 2 el siguiente 3 y no 50. Espero haberme explicado, muchas gracias.

[image: captura de ejemplo]

Comment: ¿Por qué o para qué?

Comment: Tengo que exponerlo, así que por limpieza, además para las busquedas de usuarios utilizo un bucle con jdbc que recorre uno a uno por id asi que si tengo un id 1 y el siguiente es 49 tendría 48 vueltas de bucle en las que no se hace absolutamente nada...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar lo siguiente.

1. Exporta tu base de datos, primero exporta *estructura* y *luego la información*.
2. Elimina la Tabla original.
3. Crea nuevamente la tabla, a partir de la estructura.
4. Edita el archivo SQL de los datos, eliminando el ID de todos.

Al ser la tabla nueva, los ID comenzarán nuevamente.
Como tendrás la estructura ya hecha, no deberás configurar nada.
Pero para poder asegurar su carga real, hay que dejar que el auto-increment, haga su trabajo.

Comment: Eso que dices no es una opcion cuando se trata de una base de datos de miles de registros

Answer (score 0):

Si es posible hacerlo, no creo que sea una buena práctica a menos que exista una razón de peso para hacerlo, por ejemplo, la numeración de a nivel de facturación (no puede tener huecos).

En cualquier caso, si estás haciendo búsquedas de usuarios lo mejor es usar el poder de la base de datos para ello. El auto-incremental que propones no tendría que usarse para nada si no para identificar algún registro de forma única.

No se necesita recorre por id bajo ningún motivo (salvo los casos como el expuesto anteriormente).

Se que no respondo a tu pregunta, pero es que tu pregunta no tiene mucho sentido según el planteamiento de tu pregunta y el problema que quieres solucionar.

Answer (score 0):

Ejecutando este comando te permite regresar el valor del `AUTO_INCREMENT` al valor que tu necesites.

A razón de ejemplo regresa a 1:

```
ALTER TABLE `Tu_Base_De_Datos`.`Nombre_De_Tu_Tabla`  
AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```